# A React component's function is not recognized as a function when passed in as a parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I'm trying to pass a function as a parameter for a component, however it does not see the function I pass in as a function.

Here's the page (I'm only going to provide what's imoprtant)

```
const Home = () => {
const nav = useNavigate()

const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);
const [loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useState({});
const [currentChat, setCurrentChat] = useState(undefined);
const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);

let navMenu    


const handleChatChange = (chat) => {
    setCurrentChat(chat);
}



return (

        <div id='sidebar'>
            <div>
                <Userlist users={userList} switchChat={handleChatChange}/>
            </div>
        </div>
)
```

Here is the react component that provides the error

```
const Userlist = ( props, switchChat  ) => {

const switchCurrentchat = (user) => {
    switchChat(user);
}

return (
        <div>
            <div id='home-header'>
                <h1>DevsHelp</h1>
            </div>

            <div id='userlist'>

                {props.users.map((user) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={user._id} className='user' onClick={() => switchCurrentchat(user)} >
                            <h3>{user.username}</h3>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
)}
```

Whenever switchChat is called upon, it returns an error stating "switchChat" is not a function.

If I do a console.log(user) instead of switchChat(user), it logs the user, so the function works, however it's just not reading it as a function.

If anyone could help me, I would appreciate it a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React components receive one object, commonly referred to as props.

If you wrap the params in curly braces, you can refer to them by name inside the component. Like this:

```
const Userlist = ({ users, switchChat }) => {
```

If you do this, you would need to refer to users directly inside the component. So no `props.users` anymore.

You can also just refer to them via the props object:

```
const Userlist = (props) => {
  // props.users and props.switchChat are available here
}
```